# VB Script for Outlook to automatically copy the file contents to a designated folder with a particular sender or based on Subject?

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I am a newbie to VB Scripting, what I have been trying to do is as soon as i receive a mail in Outlook from a particular sender or a particular message in the Subject line, I should copy the contents of the specified File location to other specified location 
Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be implemented using VBA macros or creating an Outlook add-in. You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class where you can check out the Subject property and do whatever you need. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) in MSDN for more information.